# Can "connected" be used to ask about one's relation with another one?

Tags: word-choice, questions, participial-adjectives

I have found many expressions with **connected** that describe two people relationship, but it is often (if not always) indicate the souls' connection. Expressions like:

> What is the meaning of two souls that feel **connected**? [source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-two-souls-that-feel-connected)
>
> 10 Signs You Have **Connected** With A Soulmate [source](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/10-signs-you-have-connected-with-a-soulmate_n_57bb4942e4b007f181994eae?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAAMgVXBNVrCbEGY2wvfy5-SPTomKwlY_3xp8WCaoOw85rLqLZD61aoxhA7CfoJJNEDSq0A6jt81Np-3PrMVx1inEhWP3IzIpDg83CJKPIHgT-Pvp4y1m8L-uAYJCkbynePdjm9u8PmwLv5O0M6dHG-Y4EShqQjZ2cCw3_9QQIZCO)

It won't work for my case as I want to inquire from someone about her relationship with another one (a male) as it seems unclear and vague to me. I want to use a structure that is similar to this one:

> Are you **connected**(?) to him?

There are many possible relations between **stranger males and females**, so I want a general word (participle adjective) that can include them all.

I also thought of **related**, but it is mostly known to ask about the relation in one's family. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/related)

I know there are many questions to ask for such cases, but, as I have stated, I want to use **a structure that has a participle adjective in which will be the main word to express the kind of the relationship I'm asking about.**

Would "connected" be a suitable fit? Or is there another word in English that will work fine?

Comment: You mean: men and women who do not know each other. Or are strangers to each other. You can feel connected or unconnected to anyone. The soul is irrelevant. [stranger men means means men who are more strange]

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Thank you for the information and answer, Lambie.